# How is the second Conv2D layer being calculated?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

This code I've got from Udacity tutorial "[Intoduction to Deep learning with TensorFlow](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud187)":

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,  activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

What I can not understand is how the second `Conv2D` being calculated after the first `MaxPooling2D`-layer.

Let's assume that we are processing 28x28px image. First `Conv2D`-layer returns (28, 28, 32) shape where 32 equals the number of filters being applied. (3,3) is the kernel size. The results than are being sent to `MaxPooling2D`-layer which reduces the size of an image from (28, 28, 32) to (14, 14, 32). Am I right here?

Now we have a shape (14, 14, 32) and send it to the second `Conv2D`-layer which will apply 64 filters using (3,3) kernel.

How is the process of applying (3,3) kernel with 64 filters will look like on our (14, 14, 32) data? Will the second `Conv2D`-layer create (14, 14, 2048) output shape or not? Or the second `Conv2D`-layer will create (14, 14, 32)x64 different blocks each for one of 64 applied filters?

I have searched all over the internet to find visually how it works to understand better this process with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this, [http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ ] will help you to understand this phenomenon visually.

Answer (score -1):

You can always view the architecture of a neural network with `model.summary()` method. The model in question has an architecture as follows:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 28, 28, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 14, 14, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 7, 7, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 3136)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               401536    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
```

Since `padding='same'` for `conv2d_1`, dim will remain `14 x 14`. Number of channels is equal to number of filters applied to this layer. Hence, the output dimension of 2nd conv layer will be `14 x 14 x 64`.

EDIT: There's wonderful resource shared by @avin in the comments below. I am adding that as part of the answer, just so that it is not lost in the comments. Thank you, @avin!

http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ provides a visual explanation of CNN.

Comment: Thanks for response, but this does not answer my question.

Comment: I understand, @AndrewShmig. I have added more details. Also, if you look at the `Output Shape` of each layer from `summary()`, that will help you understand.

Comment: I think what @AndrewShmig asks is that why each of those 32 feature maps are processed with 64 filters and not generate something like (14, 14, 32x64)? Or else how the filtering happens to convert 32 feature maps into 64? This [ http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ ] gives a visual explanation.